# FindFit problem in "Debye temperature" fitting

Tags: fitting

I am fitting the Debye temperature using FindFit, here is my code:

```
Capacity = {{1, 0.000818`}, {3, 0.0065`}, {5, 0.0243`}, {8, 
    0.0927`}, {10, 0.183`}, {15, 0.67`}, {20, 1.647`}, {25, 
    3.066`}, {30, 4.774`}, {35, 6.612`}, {40, 8.419`}, {45, 
    10.11`}, {50, 11.66`}, {55, 13.04`}, {60, 14.27`}, {65, 
    15.35`}, {70, 16.3`}, {80, 17.87`}, {90, 19.11`}, {100, 
    20.1`}, {120, 21.54`}, {140, 22.52`}, {160, 23.22`}, {180, 
    23.75`}, {200, 24.16`}, {220, 24.49`}, {240, 24.76`}, {260, 
    24.99`}, {280, 25.19`}, {300, 25.37`}};
R = 8.31451;
Cv[T_] := 
 9 R*(T/DT)^3* NIntegrate[(x^4 Exp[x])/(Exp[x] - 1)^2, {x, 0, DT/T}]

FindFit[Capacity, Cv[T], {DT, 200}, T]
```

[image]

The code is simple, but the FindFit doesn't work here, it seems that it is because the fitting parameter DT (Debye Temperature) is located at the upper limit of the integral).

How can I make a fitting like that?

The data in this question comes from this webpage: https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Quantum_Tutorials_(Rioux)/Quantum_Fundamentals/75%3A_Fitting_Debye%27s_Heat_Capacity_Equation_to_Experimental_Data_for_Silver

Comment: What is: `R` ?
?

Comment: `NIntegrate` can't evaluate because parameter `DT` isn't known!

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk `R = 8.31451 ` (found in the link)

Comment: Sorry, R=8.31451

Answer (score 9):

Now knowing `R = 8.31451` redefine your function

```
cv[T_?NumericQ, DT_?NumericQ] := 
Block[{x},9 R (T/DT)^3*NIntegrate[(x^4Exp[x])/(Exp[x] - 1)^2, {x, 0, DT/T}]];
```

The fit should minimize  `J[DT`

```
J[DT_?NumericQ] := Total@Map[(Cv[#[[1]], DT] - #[[2]])^2 &, Capacity]

Table[ {DT, J [DT]} , {DT, 150, 250, 1}] //ListPlot
```

[image]

```
NMinimize[{J[DT], 150 < DT < 250}, DT]    
(*{4.47804, {DT -> 210.986}}*)
```

I don't know why `NonlinearModelFit` is quite slow.

After ~500seconds it evaluates the same result

```
mod= NonlinearModelFit[Capacity, {cv[T,DT], 250 > DT > 150 }, {DT}  , T, Method ->"NMinimize"]  
mod["BestFitParameters"]
(*{DT -> 210.986}*)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Cv[T_?NumericQ, DT_?NumericQ] := Module[{R = 8.31451, a},
  a = DT/T;
  9  R NIntegrate[(x^4 Exp[x])/(Exp[x] - 1)^2, {x, 0, a}]/a^3]

dfit = d /. FindFit[Capacity, Cv[t, d], {d}, t]
(* 210.986 *)

g[1] = ListPlot[Capacity];
g[2] = Plot[Cv[t, dfit], {t, 0, 300}];
Show[{g[1], g[2]}]
```

[image]

The answer of @UlrichNeumann is perfect. My post does not add much to it. I simply started to type when it appeared, I thought it would be a pity to through away an almost ready post.

Comment: Thank you so much! This solution resolves my problem perfectly.